# What can cause this corruption on NTFS? (External SSD)

Tags: ssd

**Note**: This is *not* an easy question. Please read and undertand the *entire post* before answering.

---

I witnessed strange corruption behavior today that I've never seen before. All computers run Windows 8.1.

I have a Corsair Force 3 SSD that I'd bought and used in a laptop for about a year.
The SMART data seems to indicate it is healthy, as far as I can tell.
Now I've taken it out and placed it in an external USB enclosure, and I'm not using the laptop currently.

I had a ~480 MB installer that I wanted to transfer from a second laptop to a third laptop.
I thought, hey, why not just use my SSD?
So I connected the SSD and copied over the folder (which had a few small files, plus that big file).
Being a good computer user, I ran [`sync /r`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897438.aspx) to ensure the drive's caches were flushed. I waited many seconds, and then I Safely Removed the drive.

I inserted it into my third laptop and looked inside the folder, and... a few small files were gone.
Not only that, but the huge installer I had no longer had its usual icon.
Double-clicking it gave me *"The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable"*.
So I deleted the parent folder, `sync`'d and ejected it, and tried copying it over again from the first laptop.
This time, before Safely Removing the hardware, I tried to `fsutil volume dismount D:` first, and verify that the file was written before unplugging the drive. It was.
Yet I witnessed the same story: I ejected the drive and plugged it back in, and the same files were missing/corrupted. This wasn't laptop-dependent -- plugging it back into the same laptop that I'd copied it from showed the same corruption as in the third laptop.

I opened the executable with a hex editor, and noticed it was *all zeros*.
Yet when I ran CheckDisk, it said everything is fine. I even ran it with `/r` -- it said it's still fine.

Overall, I **reproduced this corruption multiple times** (at least 4 times!). The only time I finally managed to make it work was when, after the file was copied, I dismounted the volume, *copied* the file *from* the external SSD *to* my local drive to force the drive to read the SSD and flush its caches, and *then* ejected the drive. Only then did the files appear correctly after the drive was ejected... and I haven't reproduced the problem since then.

Now my question is: what are the most likely causes of this problem?

My guesses are as follows:

1. Perhaps the USB enclosure has a buggy controller.
   To me, this is the most likely option because I can't really disprove it. But I don't know how to prove it.
2. Perhaps the SSD is nearing the end of its life.
   This seems unlikely, since it worked fine as long as it was inside the first laptop, and the SMART reports look quite healthy.
3. Perhaps it's a driver software issue -- perhaps SSDs on external drives aren't well-tested?
   But I seem doubtful.
4. Perhaps I have a virus.
   ... I'm pretty sure this isn't the case; I'm just mentioning it for the sake of completeness.

But I have no idea... what can actually cause these? (Note that I saw all of these with my own eyes.)

Comment: By no means a complete answer - but you could perhaps eliminate 1. by adding as an internal drive on an available desktop, any OS, though Mac or nix might be safer.

Comment: From me too not an answer, but a bit of evidence: I have seen quite a lot of older USB-SATA bridges break on the speed of an SSD.

Comment: Are you using by any chance a usb hub to connect the SSD to your first computer?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I don't have a desktop handy unfortunately, and in any case I'm looking more to see what the cause is rather than to find a workaround.

Comment: @EugenRieck: Oh, interesting! That's a possibility...

Comment: @NuTTyX: When you say "first computer" do you mean the laptop I had used it with for about a year? If so, no -- it was inside that laptop. However, for the other two laptops, yes -- it was connected via USB.

Comment: @Mehrdad I meant the computer from where you copied the files, and I was refering specifically a USB **hub** (a multiple socket to expand the usb your computer has). I had similar issues as you described using a hub to connect an external HD to my computer.

Comment: @NuTTyX: Ohhh sorry I misunderstood. No, there was no hub -- in all cases it was directly connected to each laptop.

Comment: Without full diagnostics, testing another USB enclosure or eliminating that one as a possibility would seem to be sensible first steps. Cause/workaround would appear to be hand in hand for this exercise.